# React and Redux: Redux Custom Middleware Not Executing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

The below code is my custom redux middleware. In the removeItemFlow function, the action.type === REMOVE_ITEM is not being executed even though I press on the delete button from the frontend and the type: REMOVE_ITEM and payload successfully execute but the middleware is not catching it. I have been wrestling with this for two days now so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

//Custom Redux Middleware

```
export const getItemsFlow = ({getState, dispatch}) => next => action => {
  next(action);
  if (action.type === GET_ITEMS) {
    dispatch(apiGetRequest('/api/items/water/', setAuthorizationHeader(getState), FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS, FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR));
    dispatch(loadingData());
  }

};


export const processItemsCollection = ({dispatch}) => next => action => {
  next(action);
  if (action.type === FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS) {
    dispatch(updateItems(action.payload.data));
  }

};


export const removeItemFlow = ({getState, dispatch}) => next => action => {
  next(action);

  if(action.type === REMOVE_ITEM){
      console.log(action.type)
          dispatch(apiDeleteRequest(`/api/items/water/${action.payload.id}`, setAuthorizationHeader(getState), REMOVE_ITEM_SUCCESS, REMOVE_ITEM_ERROR));
    }


};

export const itemsMdl = [getItemsFlow, processItemsCollection, removeItemFlow];
```

//Redux Store

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export const store     = createStore(
rootReducer,
composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...itemsMdl, ...api),
)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few observations here.  None of them are a direct solution to your issue, but they may ultimately point you towards an alternate approach that doesn't have this problem.

First, none of your custom middleware are actually returning the result of `next(action)`.  In this case, it's probably not breaking anything, but a good Redux middleware should always try to return the result it was given:

```js
const result = next(action);

// do more logic here if you want to
return result;
```

Second, you don't need to separate this into three different middleware. You could do it as a single middleware with multiple conditions inside.

Third, this really feels like it doesn't need to be a custom middleware at all.  There's nothing *wrong* with using custom Redux middleware, but in this case what you seem to be doing can be accomplished a lot more simply by using [Redux Toolkit's `createAsyncThunk` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), which will automatically dispatch actions based on async requests and promises.

Also, you should definitely be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) to write your logic, including `configureStore` to replace the store setup code you have there.

As for the specific error you described: I don't *immediately* see a bug, so it's hard to know what's going on.  I'd suggest adding logging in these middleware to see if they're even running, and if the actions you expect are actually reaching them.

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed response. I learned a lot from your post. In terms of having a single middleware with multiple conditions inside, are you saying for example, I should have all the conditions inside getItemsFlow?

Comment: In that scenario, yes. Again, you _can_ write multiple custom middleware to handle different use cases - nothing wrong with that. But for this use case, there's no reason to split this logic across three separate middleware, especially when they're all clearly implementing pieces of the same use case.